# How to hyphenate "exemple"?

Tags: typographie, trait-d-union

I am lost as to where to find a reference for hyphenation (*trait d'union*) rules or syllables decomposition of words in French. English dictionaries generally provide this information by default, but neither [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/exemple), [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/exemple) nor [TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=1286812620;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) gives this info.

Right now I'm unsure how to properly hyphenate *exemple*. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd not. There are three syllables but X between vowels is not a good place, neither is before the p as the ending e is "muet"

Comment: I think this link will be useful: http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/orthographe/coupure_des_mots.html

Comment: @Unfrancophone Mute last syllables are not ruled out when they have three letters or more.

Comment: @jlliagre, there is a reason for which I said "not a good place" and not "must be prevented at all cost".  Hyphenation is a way to avoid issues in typesetting, there are usually several way to handle the situation, all of them with various drawbacks which may depend on the situation.  To accept "exem-ple", avoiding it should cause some other problems which I'd prefer to avoid even more strongly than accepting it.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Granted, *exemple* is indeed a word with which there is no consensus about hyphenation rules.

Answer (score 3):

The basic rule is to hyphenate between syllables but there are [many other rules](http://www.guide-typographie.com/Coupures.htm) that forbids (or at least strongly discourage) some hyphenations and specify where precisely the hyphenation should occur in some cases.

Here one of these rules is preventing the first syllable to be isolated because its ending "x" is followed by a vowel. The last syllable has a mute "e" which would have ruled out hyphenation should it had [less than three letters](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4873) but this isn't the case here.

The only possible hyphenation is then before the last syllable:

> exem-ple

[image]

Note that there is no full consensus about the rules, this [page](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/orthographe/coupure_des_mots.html) is stricter and states *exemple* cannot be hyphenated.